# Динамическая смена определенного фрагмента текста

Tags: java, android

Пишу свой песенник в Android Studio и есть необходимость менять тональность аккордов при нажатии на кнопку, каким способом можно реализовать данную опцию?
Вот пример сайта, где это работает, есть две кнопки справа и слева от надписи тональность
http://amdm.ru/akkordi/ddt/3054/osen/

Answer (score 1):

1. Находите в разметке тестовое поле (`TextView`)
2. Находите в разметке кнопку (Button)
3. Вешаете на кнопку слушатель нажатий.
4. В нём меняете текст `TextView`.

Comment: А если объем текстовых данных очень большой? Как сделать так, чтобы программа могла отличить обычный текст от нужного мне фрагмента, который надо поменять?

Comment: Что значит "очень большой объём", "обычный текст" и "нужный мне фрагмент"? На заданный вами вопрос в его текущей формулировке невозможно дать более полный ответ, чем тот, что я уже написал. Вам надо задачу поделить на части и делать всё по порядку.

Comment: Большой объем это значит, что текст будет браться из бд, а ну вводится на каждое активити или фрагмент вручную. А определенный фрагмент это значит, что из текста в активити программа должна отличить текст от аккорда и только аккорд менять, а текст оставлять неизменным. Например, заключить аккорд в <> и уже как-то распознавать его..

Comment: Ну так запишите куда-нить все возможные аккорды и ищите совпадения с ними во входящем тексте.

Comment: А каким методом можно искать совпадения? Есть ли пример такого кода?

Comment: У строк есть методы для поиска - посмотрите документацию. Искать можно по совпадениям и регулярными выражениями.

Comment: Готовый парсер аккордов в тексте не существует (уверен на 99.(9)%). Придётся вам его написать. Но сложным это не будет.

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду пробовать